# How to fix Angular validator allows minHours to be submitted regardless of error

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

There is a custom validator that currently is not working when the user confirms changes to the minHours. The user is able to save their changes even when the validator displays an error. What would be the best way to fix this issue in Angular?

Here is the requirement: When retireeClassLink = 'No' the minHrs should not be able to be submitted below min value. And when the plan does not have the slug, then the min value can be decreased (including value of 0) or increased.

**ProductsFormInitializer.TS**

```
private minHoursValidator(formControl: FormControl) {
        const required = EbValidators.required(formControl);
        if (required || this.data.is2To9) {
            return required;
        }
        if (formControl.parent && formControl.parent.parent && formControl.parent.parent.get('erppEeMinEligHrsNo')) {
            let min = +FormUtils.getControl(formControl.parent.parent, 'erppEeMinEligHrsNo').value;
            if (formControl.parent.parent.value.retireClassLink && formControl.parent.parent.value.retireClassLink.ebBenefitValues.benvalBenefitValue === 'Yes') {
                min = 0;
            }
            if (+formControl.value < min) {
                return { 'minHrs': 'Hours cannot be below ' + min + '.' };
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


this.addValidator(classForm, 'erclasHrWorkEligNo', [this.minHoursValidator.bind(this)]);
```

I was thinking explicitly adding the following condition:

```
else if (formControl.parent.parent.value.retireClassLink && formControl.parent.parent.value.retireClassLink.ebBenefitValues.benvalBenefitValue === 'No') {
                return { 'minHrs': 'Hours cannot be below ' + min + '.' };
            }
```

Comment: In form where you add this validator ?

Comment: this.addValidator(classForm, 'erclasHrWorkEligNo', [this.minHoursValidator.bind(this)]);